# Get(Uri.http) does not working in flutter when get WorldTime API

Tags: flutter, worldtimeapi

i start studying Flutter.
I got a problem when i tried to get Worl Time Api.
Please help me to solve it. Thank a lot.

Here is my code:

```
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  Future getTime() async {
    Response response =
        await get(Uri.http('worldtimeapi.org', '/api/timezone/Asia/Bangkok'));
    print('xx');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('World Time'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

System stuck in Response row, it did not run Print();

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MvocS.jpg)

Comment: try override initState(){
getTime();
}

Comment: Can you share the code where you have defined the `get` method ?

Comment: @TheAlphamerc: 
in file pubspec.yaml:
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  http: ^0.13.3

and in main.dart:
 import 'package:http/http.dart';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `getTime` function in `initState(){}` like this:

```
Future getTime() async {
    print('hi');
    try {
      Response response =
          await get(Uri.http('worldtimeapi.org', '/api/timezone/Asia/Bangkok'));
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
    print('xx');
  }


    @override
  void initState() {
    getTime();
    super.initState();
  }
```

if it not working, check your emulator internet.